# How to put some code at the footer of generated files for ANTLR4 (C#)

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I'm working with ANTLR4 for C#.

I know there is a way to put something like this for the header in the grammar file

```
@header {
#pragma warning disable 1591,1574
}
```

Is there a similar thing for footer? I want to put the #pragma restore at the end of the generated C# parser and lexer C# files.

Cheers,
Van

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to add items to the footer.

In addition:

1. There is no reason to for the items you listed, because you are literally asking for the ability to programmatically add a `#pragma` that affects the code following the pragma at a location that *guarantees* it will never have an effect.
2. Starting with the next release, warning 1591 will be suppressed in all files generated by the C# target. See [pull request #22](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/pull/22)
3. If you are getting warning CS1574, then you've found a bug in the generated code that needs to be [reported](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/issues), not suppressed.